# How to run multiple c++ executable at batch?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bunch of C++ executable that I want to run in batch. Suppose I have three executables "101", "233", "330", I try to run them like:

```
ls | grep '^[0-9]*$' | xargs -n1 ./
```

But, I got an error

```
xargs: ./: Permission denied
```

Is there any way I can run those executables with one-liner instead of writing a shell for loop?

I doubt my simple inquiry should be answered somewhere, but I have no luck finding it through google.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're misusing `xargs`.  Try...

```
ls | grep '^[0-9]*$' | xargs -n1 -IARG ./ARG
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got `xargs: ./ARG: No such file or directory` message. I'm on Mac OS but not sure if this is the problem.

Comment: Just tried on a macbook and it seems ok.  Add the `-t` flag to the `xargs` invocation and check that it prints what you'd expect.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the command `ls | grep '^[0-9]*$' | xargs -n1 -t -IARG ./ARG` and I got `./ARG xargs: ./ARG: No such file or directory`. I just check the man page. It seems that `-I` will replace the provided pattern (e.g. `ARG`) to each input line. There is no executable named `ARG` and I think that's why the error raised.

Comment: No, `ARG` *should* be replaced by the names read from the standard input so I'm not quite sure what's going on.